# Facebook PHP SDK 3.1.1 "Error validating access token" after Go to App page

Tags: php, facebook, api, access-token, facebook-login

I'm having some strange issues building an iframe app for Facebook. The app seems to get stuck in an infinite loop on the Go To App page.

After the user authorizes the app in the Go To App page, and returns to the app, the /me api call throws the "Error validating access token" exception. I checked and there is a valid access token in the Signed Request (tested with the facebook access token debuggin tool). I tried setting that with the setAccessToken() method unsuccessfully.
The getUser() method successfully returns the user ID, but it still hangs on the /me api call.

This doesn't happen in every browser, i'm just seeing it in Chrome sometimes in a no clear pattern. I fixed it in IE using the P3P header. It works fine in Firefox.

I pretty much stuck and i'm out of hair to pull out so any ideas are welcome. Thanks a lot.

The full error message: "Error validating access token: You cannot access the app till you log in to www.facebook.com and follow the instructions given."

Some code below.

```
$this->_facebook = new Facebook(
    array(
        'appId' => $this->_config['appId'],
        'secret' => $this->_config['secret'],
        'cookie' => true,
        'fileUpload' => true
    )
);

$this->_signedRequest = $this->_facebook->getSignedRequest();

// Doing something with signed request, not FB related

$this->_userId = $this->_facebook->getUser();

if($this->_userId) {
    try{
        // At this line the "Error validating access token" error shows up
        $this->_user = $this->_facebook->api('/me');

        // Some more irrelevant code here

    } catch (Exception $e){
        $this->_facebook->destroySession();
        $this->_facebookLogin(false);
    }
} else {
    $this->_facebook->destroySession();
    $this->_facebookLogin(false);
}

// The _facebookLogin method
public function _facebookLogin($perms = 'email,user_birthday,publish_stream,video_upload'){
    $data = array(
        'fbconnect' => 0,
        'redirect_uri' => 'aredirecturl.com'
    );

    if(!empty($perms)) {
        $data['scope'] = $perms;
    }
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.top.location.href = "'.$this->_facebook->getLoginUrl($data).'";</script>';
    exit;
}
```

Comment: can you put your full code (for example in this code `public function _facebookLogin` is wrong

Comment: i am facing the same problem, chrome as well. @Cazacu Vlad if you have found solution please post here thanks

Answer (score 0):

Edit this part

```
// At this line the "Error validating access token" error shows up
$this->_user = $this->_facebook->api('/me');
```

to this

```
// At this line the "Error validating access token" error shows up
$this->_user = $this->facebook->api('/me','GET');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that didn't do it. As far as i saw, GET is the default for graph calls, so it was already using that.

Answer (score 0):

What about destroying your session by hand? Did you debug these parameters?

```
unset($_SESSION['fb_'.$YOUR_API_KEY.'_code']);
unset($_SESSION['fb_'.$YOUR_API_KEY.'_access_token']);
unset($_SESSION['fb_'.$YOUR_API_KEY.'_user_id']);
unset($_SESSION['fb_'.$YOUR_API_KEY.'_state']);
```

I am almost using the same code as you,but I'm not using `fileUpload` and cookie parameters.